# Control the Bokeh xwheel_zoom tool using a Bokeh widget/callback

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using xwheel_zoom (WheelZoomTool) for a Bokeh chart with datetime axis.

```
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools='xwheel_zoom, crosshair, undo, reset')
```

I provide pandas TimeStamp as the x value of this chart. For example:`pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc')`. The x axis range of this chart is for the last 24 hours.

`start = pd.Timestamp.now(tz='utc') - pd.Timedelta(hours=24)`

Using xwheel_zoom, I could zoom in to see my chart better for a given time (e.g. last hour).

Is there any way in Bokeh I could achieve this zoom functionality by coding or connecting to the xwheel_zoom and controling it with a Bokeh widget (e.g. Bokeh dropdown)?

My objective is to have a button to click on and let it show me the zoomed in x_axis for the last hour, or show the chart between a datetime period I define. Idealy, I do not want to re-define/re-draw the chart again and just want to control the xwheel_zoom functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any tools to do that. Just change the desired range in a callback. Something like:

```py
b = Button()

def update():
    p.x_range.update(start=0, end=1)

b.on_click(update)
```

The example will work only if used with `bokeh serve`. If you're not using that, you can rewrite the code to work with `CustomJS` and `js_on_click`.